# How to troubleshoot a dead Sony Vaio VPCSA?

Tags: sony-vaio

Yesterday morning it was in sleeping mode, then I pressed spacebar to activate the laptop and it turned itself off. Then it can't get started. It gets power since the battery light is lit. The store were I bought it (Sony Center Stockholm) has gone bankrupt.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Does it work directly on AC power without the battery inserted?

Comment: @Karan I just spoke with Sony support who told me to remove the battery which I've just done and they'd call me back in 5-10 minutes. Thank you

Comment: @Karan it's working again. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad it's up and running again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As [posted](https://superuser.com/revisions/546246/2) by [Nick Rosencrantz](https://superuser.com/users/19548/nick-rosencrantz))

After speaking with Sony support, I could remove the battery, start the laptop and then put the battery back restoring the system.